# Determine whether an integer is a palindrome

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, ecmascript-6, palindrome

**The task**

> Determine whether an integer is a palindrome. An integer is a
>   palindrome when it reads the same backward as forward.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: 121 Output: true
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: -121 Output: false Explanation: From left to right, it reads
>   -121. From right to left, it becomes 121-. Therefore it is not a palindrome.
>
> Example 3:
>
> Input: 10 Output: false Explanation: Reads 01 from right to left.
>   Therefore it is not a palindrome. Follow up:
>
> Could you solve it without converting the integer to a string?

**My solution**
with converting number to string

```
const isPalindrome = n => n >= 0 && Number([...`${n}`].reverse().join("")) === n;

console.log(isPalindrome(121));
```

**My solution**
without converting number to string

```
const isPalindrome2 = n => {
  if (n < 0) { return false; }
  let num = Math.abs(n);
  const arr = [];
  let i = 1;
  while (num > 0) {
    const min = num % (10 ** i);
    num = num - min;
    i++;
    arr.push(min);
  }
  i = i - 2;
  let j = 0;
  return n === arr.reduce((res, x) => {
    const add = (x/ (10 ** j)) * (10 ** i);
    res += add;
    i--;
    j++;
    return res;
  }, 0);
};

console.log(isPalindrome2(121));
```

Comment: That's an awfully convoluted way to check for your objective. Can you tell us more about why you did it this way?

Comment: I wanted to solve it without converting the number to a string. @Mast

Comment: That explains it in part, but it's still an odd way to do it. I hope my answer points out why I was so surprised.

Comment: @thadeuszlay Palindrome is not defined on numbers, it's defined on strings. In this case you want decadic string representing the given number. You *have* to convert it to a string or a similar representation (e.g. array of decadic digits).

Comment: @Sulthan the Point is not to use strings (as described in the task)

Comment: @thadeuszlay In my opinion it's a bad question. You will use a String anyway, even if it's in a roundabout way.

Comment: @Sulthan well, you don't necessarily need an array or string. The answers show how you can do this without splitting up the digits. But it _is_ true that you need to know the base, and that a fully explicit version of the question should ask whether the base-10 (or whatever) representation of the integer is a palindrome, since that's a property of the representation but not of the integer itself.

Comment: "10" is a palindrome. While standard representations are made of symbols ("convert to string") "010" is still a valid and correct representation of "10".  So, either convert to string is the valid approach, or the concept of the number is the valid approach - the latter means numbers like "10", "200" etc are valid palindromes.

Comment: @AJD this is Javascrpit as such 010 is prefixed with 0 making it an octal which represents the base 10 value 8. Most computer languages prefix or post fix numbers to define the base. In javascript without a prefix all numbers are base 10, `0x` for hex, `0` for octal, `0b` for binary, and postfix `n` for big ints (AKA dec strings). The problem shows no prefix, thus the solution is clearly a decimal one (base 10)

Comment: @Blindman67: You missed the point. Any representation of a number uses symbols and 010 is as valid as the representation for "ten" (decimal) as 10 is. Yes, if this was in a line of code then 010 could represent Octal - but it is not, it is in user input and users of an application or function will (well, may) be blissfully unaware of the vagaries of any particular language. However, this does go to support the earlier comment that this is a poorly considered task. My key point - palindromes are about symbols (strings) and can only be about symbols, not abstract concepts like numbers or words.

Comment: @AJD the problem as stated in the question "Determine whether an integer is a palindrome" would suggest that palindromes can be about numbers (as my answer demonstrates without the use of symbols). But to take your argument further, computers use charge to hold states and process those states, the whole concept of numbers in computers is already highly abstract. You can selectively draw a line to what level of abstraction should apply, however the question put that line down for all to see.

Comment: @Blindman67: No, the problem is that the question is implying that the search is on a number (an abstract concept), not the representation of a number according to rules. The task description uses "01" as an example, so "010" is also legal (i.e. leading zeroes to be counted). Representations count - is the number "5", "5.0" or "101"? An additional point - the task is language agnostic, so your other comments regarding Java-specific encoding are not valid.

Comment: @AJD There are 10 types of people. Those that read binary and those that don't. Its funny only to those that do, but only because we all read it as ten until prompted to read two. Common use defines the standard, specialist use requires explicit definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Count digits in positive integer

You can get the number of digits using `log10`

eg

```
Math.log10(13526); // is 4.131169383089324
const digits = Math.ceil(Math.log10(13526)); // 5
```

You can get the unit value eg 423 is 100 or 256378 is 100000 by raising 10 to the power of the number of digits minus one. Well not for powers of 10

eg

```
unit = 10 ** (Math.ceil(Math.log10(13526)) -1); // 10000
unit = 10 ** (Math.ceil(Math.log10(10000)) -1); // 1000 wrong for power of 10 number
```

To get the value we want we need to floor the log first

```
unit = 10 ** Math.floor(Math.log10(10000)); // 10000
unit = 10 ** Math.floor(Math.log10(13526)); // 10000 correct
```

or

```
unit = 10 ** (Math.log10(10000) | 0); // 10000
unit = 10 ** (Math.log10(13526) | 0); // 10000
```

### Get digit at position of positive integer

To get the digit at any position in a number divide it by 10 raised to the power of the digit position get the remainder of that divided by 10 and floor it.

```
const digitAt = (val, digit) => Math.floor(val / 10 ** digit % 10);
```

or

```
const digitAt = (val, digit) => val / 10 ** digit % 10 | 0;

// Note  brackets added only to clarify order and are not needed
// ((val / (10 ** digit)) % 10) | 0;

digitAt(567, 0);  // 7
digitAt(567, 1);  // 6
digitAt(567, 2);  // 5
```

### Positive integer a palindrome in \$O(1)\$ space

With that info you can then build a function that does test in \$O(1)\$ space, as you do not need to store the digits in an array for later comparison.

To keep performance up we can avoid the slower versions of some operation. For `floor` we can `| 0` (note that for large numbers > 2**31-1 you must use `floor`) and for `**` use `Math.pow`

Rather than do the full calculation to get the digit we can store the unit value of the digit we want for the top and bottom and multiply by 10 to move up and divide by 10 to move down.

```
function isPalindrome(num) {
    var top = Math.pow(10, Math.log10(num) | 0), bot = 1;
    while (top >= bot) {
        if ((num / top % 10 | 0) !== (num / bot % 10 | 0)) { return false }
        top /= 10;
        bot *= 10;
    }
    return true;
}
```

- The function will returns `false` for negative numbers but is not optimized for them
- The function only works on integer values less than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` which is `9007199254740991`

In terms of performance the above function is 5 times faster for a 16 digit palindrome `2192123993212912` and 10-11 times faster for  a non palindrome of 16 digits

Comment: Don't suggest floating-point arithmetic when solving integer problems.

Comment: @RolandIllig Really??? Are you unfamiliar with Javascript? . Using math operators `/`, `*`, `%` evaluate as doubles, Meaning that what you are saying  is dont use math operators to solve integer problems,

Comment: The crucial point is that IEEE 754-2008 guarantees that the `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `sqrt` operators produce results that are as close to the mathematical truth as possible. There is no such guarantee for `log10` or `sin`, and thus using these functions may introduce rounding errors.

Comment: Besides this, my advice also applies to all those who will copy this code into the language of their choice and just set the type to `int64_t`. The algorithm and the code should be so fundamentally correct that they work with any integer type.

Comment: @RolandIllig What??? You are saying, all answers no matter what the tag must be language neutral, I think I will avoid that complication. Anyways the | operator converts to int 32 and Math.log10 in javascript will never let `(Math.log10(n)|0) !== (Math.log10(n+1)|0)` be true, where n is positive int (excluding 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999... ). So prove me wrong, all you need is a number for `n`

Comment: @RolandIllig By the way did you read my answer "only works on integer values less than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`" a clear warning regarding possible rounding errors

Comment: @RolandIllig read my comment again

Answer (score 5):

Your second solution is awfully complicated for something simple.

You start out alright.  No negative number can be a palindrome, so we can discount those. However, 0 is always a palindrome, so you're discounting that while you shouldn't.

You do a lot of complicated math *and* use an array. You could use either, but shouldn't use both. There are a couple of mathematical approaches to solve this, but you should be able to use those without iterating over the individual numbers or splitting it up at all. The most obvious solution however, is using an array and direct comparisons, without any math.

Say we got `1221`. Split it up. `[1, 2, 2, 1]`. Iterate over the array, comparing every nth character to the last-nth character. 0th to 3rd. 1st to 2nd.

Say we got `92429`. Split it up. `[9, 2, 4, 2, 9]`. Ignore the middle character. Handle the rest like it's an even-length number.

Based on those 2 cases, you should be able to figure out a much simpler algorithm.

**Note:** This answers the explicit question. Implicitly, you should wonder whether arrays should be allowed for this challenge. After all, iterating over a string or an array, it's not that different. I strongly suspect they want you to use the math-only approach.

Another approach, which is somewhat math-based and you should beware of overflows, is simply reversing the number.
In pseudo-code, that would look something like this:

```
reverse = 0
while (number != 0) {
  reverse = reverse * 10 + number % 10;
  number /= 10;
}
```

Check the input versus its reversed number. If they are the same, it's a palindrome.

But this still uses extra memory to hold the additional integer we just created.

Can it be done without? Absolutely. But I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: How would you split it up?

Comment: You are converting the number to a string anyway, even if you don't store the string anywhere. A number is an abstract concept. To represent it, you need a string, either binary or a decadic (or any other base). When you start working with decimal representation, you are using a string representation. You cannot define palindrome without a string.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, but that's a philosophical discussion, not a review.

Comment: You could modify the last approach to stop when reverse >= number, and then evaluate. Voila, no danger of overflow.

Comment: @Deduplicator when using your approach to test `121` and `1221`, the code needs two separate tests. One for odd number of digits, one for even. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @RolandIllig Right, the final determination is a two-part test, allowing for a simpler loop.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you should generate all those objects and arrays?
And the second code additionally looks quite complex.

Testing whether a number is palindromic is actually quite simple:

```
function isPalindrome(num) {
    if (num % 10 == 0) {
        return num == 0
    }
    var rev = 0
    while (rev < num) {
        rev = rev * 10 + num % 10
        num /= 10
    }
    return rev == num || rev / 10 == num
}
```

Comment: This is JavaScript, therefore it's better to compare using `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: This doesn't work for an input of `10`

Comment: @mph85 Fixed trailing zeros, thanks.